# Cluster, MKMapView show many time same annotation

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

So, I have a swift application (swift 3) who use a map, in this map I have many annotation who gets up to date when user change region of map.

I wanted to use the pod "Cluster", I add it and when I zoom in to show what was in the cluster, the annotations appear several times almost at the same place (some time it form a circle, see picture)

[image]

I have already tried to filter my list to get only once instance of annotation in cluster but it doesn't works.

This method is call each time the user change region :

```
   func createAnnotations(pois list:[PlaceModel]) {
    poiAnnotations.removeAll()

    let filteredAnnotations = mapView.annotations.filter { annotation in
        //if annotation is MKUserLocation { return false }          // don't remove MKUserLocation

        if let temp = annotation.subtitle, let value = temp {
            return value == "Place"
        }
        return false
    }

    clusterManager.remove(poiAnnotations)
    clusterManager.remove(filteredAnnotations)

    for poi in list {
        let centerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, longitude: mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude)
        if poi.getLocation().distance(from: centerLocation) > Double(Constants.POI_Radius) {
            continue
        }

        let annotation = Annotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: poi.latitude!, longitude: poi.longitude!)
        annotation.title = poi.name!
        annotation.subtitle = "Place"
        annotation.type =  .image( Images.MapPins.velhop)


        // For first value
        if poiAnnotations.isEmpty {
            poiAnnotations.append(annotation)
        }

        for pois in poiAnnotations {
            if poiAnnotations.contains(where: {$0.title == poi.name}) {
                // Do nothing
            } else {
                poiAnnotations.append(annotation)
            }
        }
    }    
    clusterManager.add(poiAnnotations)
}
```

And Here the place where the clusters and the annotations are created :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let annotation = annotation as? ClusterAnnotation {

        let identifier = "Cluster"
        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        // Type for cluster
        let color = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 149/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        let type:ClusterAnnotationType = .color(color, radius: 25)

        if let view = view as? BorderedClusterAnnotationView {
            view.annotation = annotation
            view.configure(with: type)
        } else {
            view = BorderedClusterAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier, type: type, borderColor: .white)
        }
        return view
    } else {

        let identifier = "Pin"
        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView

        if let view = view {
            view.annotation = annotation      
        } else {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

I tried several things that did not succeed.. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `let annotation = ClusterAnnotation()` instead of `Annotation()`

Comment: It doesn't works, nothing change.

Comment: have you got solution yet?. because i have same problem.